# Всю ли память сразу выделяет Python под объект?

Tags: python, память

Смотря в таблицу использования Python памяти, вижу, что на int выделяется 24 бита(64 система), когда на int в TurboPascal выделяется 8 бит. Так вот, Python при создании объекта численного типа выделяет сразу ВСЕ 24 бита или может использовать меньше, если число само по себе маленькое размером?

Comment: ЕМНИП, на int в Pascal выделяется обычно 32 бита (на 32-битных ОС). Покажите пример кода, как вы выделяете и как проверяете размер?

Comment: @Kromster, нам преподаватель сказал, что выделяется 8 бит в Pascal.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Turbo Pascal

Comment: @GunTHE на практическом занятии присвойте переменной типа int число -1000 и спросите у преподавателя, как это получилось, если 8 бит не могут обеспечить достаточной ёмкости.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, но ведь значение -1000 можно присвоить int. Или при присвоении, памяти выделится гораздо больше 8 бит?

Comment: @GunTHE именно. Похоже, что вам преподаватель некомпетентен. Или вы его не так поняли.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В Python нет примитивных типов, всё - объекты. В том числе целые числа, которые в CPython представлены в памяти структурой [PyLongObject](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/longobject.h#L10), содержащей счётчик ссылок, ссылку на объект типа, массив чисел типа [uint32_t](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) и его длину.

```
struct _longobject {  // С развёрнутыми макросами
    Py_ssize_t ob_refcnt;
    PyTypeObject *ob_type;
    Py_ssize_t ob_size;
    digit ob_digit[1];
};
```

Такая структура позволяет хранить в переменной типа int число любой размерности, если для него хватает оперативной памяти.

Comment: указатель на объект типа...